# Mac pycharm can't install lxml package

Tags: python, pycharm, lxml, xcrun

I am facing below error from pycharm IDE:

> ERROR: b'xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun\n'

I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Xcode Command-line Tools needs to be updated.

Go back to your terminal and hit:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You'll then receive:

```
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

You will be prompted at this point in a window to update Xcode Command Line tools. (which may take a while)

open a new terminal window and your development tools should be returned.

**Addition:** With any major or semi-major update you'll need to update the command line tools in order to get them functioning properly again. Check Xcode with any update. This goes beyond Mojave...

**After that restart your terminal**